# I want to combine values from two collections to get data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are user collections and bulletin collections. The bulletin collection has the author's uid. I want to give data to the username matching the uid in the User collection, not the author's uid, before giving the bulletin board's information to the client.

### User Schema

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  "userId": String,
  "userPw": String,
  "userName": String,
});

var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

### Board Schema

```
var baseBoardSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  authorUid: String,
});

var freeBoardSchema = new Schema({
  baseBoard : { type: baseBoardSchema, default: baseBoardSchema}
});

var freeBoard = mongoose.model('freeBoard', freeBoardSchema);
```

---

So I did below. But it generate error. How I do?

```
FreeBoard.aggregate()
.lookup({
  from: User,
  localField: 'baseBoard.authorUid',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as : 'users'
})
.exec(function(error, freeBoards) {
  if(error) {
    //error
  }
});
```

Comment: The `from` argument expects a "collection name" as a "string" and not the model. You can just get the collection name from the model as a property by. `from: User.collection.name` instead. Or just `from: 'users'` which "should" be the default name. It actually does say "string" in the usage when you look at the documentation.

Comment: Also `localField` is just the relative path from the present model as well. So `localField: 'authorUid``

Comment: thank you so much!! I solved this problem.

Comment: I have a question. I want to get only one value, same as authorUid and _id in the users collection. But I do not know why all the documents in the user collection are loaded. How I can?